# Как защитить php код, чтобы сайт работал только на заданном домене

Tags: php

Как можно закодировать часть PHP кода, так чтобы сайт работал только на том домене который указан в коде, а на другом домене не работал. Какие варианты существуют для решения данного вопроса.

Comment: По большому счёту — никак. В любом случае код можно понять, исправить и приспособить к другим условиям. Вы можете лишь надеяться отсрочить неизбежное. Впрочем, есть один рабочий вариант: если код будет настолько плох, что никто им не заинтересуется, будьте уверены, что его не украдут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если код работает на сервере под контролем «злодеев», любую техническую защиту можно обойти. Вопрос времени и стоимости. Сможете сделать это настолько сложным, что ломать (и перепродавать?) дороже, чем купить – вы победили.

Вариант – **держать код у себя**. Пусть их сайт работает с вашего сервера. Вы будете «заниматься поддержкой и обновлением» и пр. а они вам регулярно (!) платить за хостинг и апдейты.

Можно сделать небольшие **закладки в код**, которые будут случайно, очень редко, маяковать вашему серверу – так вы узнаете, где ваш код работает – домен, IP. Или заранее позаботьтесь о каких-то уникальных сигнатурах, видимых на сайте извне, и индексируемых поисковиками – чтобы вы могли найти все инсталляции вашего кода через Яндекс/Google.

Подумайте о **юридическиской защите**. В некоторых странах она совсем не работает, в некоторых (напр. Германии) – вполне, и приносит всем - от владельцев права до юристов, занимающихся вопросом, ощутимую прибыль.

Наконец, поступите нетривиально – выложите ваш код **в открытый доступ**. А деньги берите за премиум возможности и поддержку.

Непосредственно по теме вопроса. Отличная школа – **изучение чужого кода**. Скачайте коммерческие продукты на php – темы/плагины WordPress, компоненты Joomla и т.п. и посмотрите, как в них реализована защита – напр. запись о копирайте, назойливо вылезающая на всех страницах, или отключение через месяц пробного периода. «Изучить» значит взломать, докопавшись до сути защиты. Встречаются забавные реализации обфускации кода, замены похожих символов в названиях переменых, методов, констант: `COPY_CHECK` vs. `C0PY_СHECK`, `base64` кодирование и пр.

Answer (score 8):

1. Заложить проверку домена в ядро самого приложения.
2. [Обфусцировать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) весь код 
   или только само ядро.

Но те кто захотят украсть ваш код, в любом случае смогут это сделать с помощью [деобфускации PHP кода](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137459/). Как не крути – 100% гарантии нет.

Еще ссылки по теме:

- [PHP Obfuscator 2.5.2](http://forum.antichat.ru/threads/417809/)
- [Обфускация онлайн](http://wb0.ru/phpobf.php)

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `ioncube` – он обсфуцирует код с помощью ключа.

Answer (score 1):

Кому надо - все равно раскодируют, вопрос только в том, сколько труда для этого понадобится

А так - проверять в нескольких местах в самом коде (причём разными методами, да простят боги DRY)

Можно перегнать в байт-код Zend Guard'ом, если есть возможность ставить модули на хостинг, в теории это надёжнее, чем просто обфусцировать

Answer (score 1):

Можно скомпилить (HipHop), будет быстрее работать, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_(%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)